# Python: send data to socket on connect

Tags: python, sockets, input

I've got a (third party) socket, that accepts input. I can call it from commandline with:

```
nc www.host.com 1234 < inputfile.txt
```

I then get a response and the connection closes. 
I try to write a python script that automates calling this service. I want to send data directly (not from a file) to it.

I tried it with a python script and socket.send() and recv() function. But the service gets no input on connection, so it returns an error and closes. when calling .send I get a broken pipe error (cause the connection got closed)
my code (snippet):

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send(data)
data = s.recv(256)
```

the error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

The error is because the socket connection is closed by the server immediately if there are is no data. the .send is too late.

Is sending data on connect possible using python (I assume it is)

Comment: Did you try to "write a python script that automates calling this service"? Did it work? If not, did it produce an error mesage?

Comment: @Robᵩ of course I tried ;) edited my question

Comment: What error is produced? What code did you use?

Comment: And yes it is possible... _Everything_ is possible

Comment: Try using connect_ex and see what it returns i.e. does it even connect?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me, after I add in the missing lines (https://gist.github.com/rha1063/1af356991e0edff576ba04aa311dceca). Since the error isn't in what you posted, it must be in what you chose not to post. Please reduce your program to the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Please copy-paste that entire short program into your question. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: @Robᵩ Your code works because Google waits for received data after the connect (example: nc google.com 80 -> connection is established, then write GET / and hit enter -> works.) in my case, if there is no data right at connect, the socket gets closed by the server. If I use your code snippet and use my host+port, I get the same error as in my description. That'S because the socket is closed BEFORE the send.

Comment: `nc` is not magic, and is doing pretty much the same thing as your code snippet: `socket()`, `connect()`, `send()`, `recv()`. I would capture the connection setup packets with wireshark to try to see what's happening on the network, and `strace` (on both sides if necessary) to try to see what's happening system call-wise. (And also do `strace` on `nc` and contrast with the python script for insight.)

Comment: @kappadoky - In that case, the error seems to be with your server. Can you post your server code? Or, if it is a commercial server, can you tell us what it is? I don't mean to repeat myself, but whatever you can do to provide a reproducible test case will improve the likelihood and the quality of the answers you receive.

Comment: @Robᵩ the server is whale.hacking-lab.com the port 5555 
I do not own this server nor do I have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

My answer for now (I post this as an answer because it works, but I won't accept it because it's ugly as hell) is to use netcat and call it from python. 
This works because it's like using nc in command-line. The approach is ugly as hell though:

```
proc = Popen("nc www.host.com 1234", shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
data, err = proc.communicate(data)
```

This is for Python 2.7, for Python 3 there is [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). (Got no code snippet for this because I coded the script in 2.7)